# how to do the integration between IBMMQ with RabbitMQ

Tags: spring-integration

How can we integrate between IBMMQ and RabbitMQ. One of our customer used IBMMQ and i think IBMMQ cannot directly communicate with RabbitMQ. There has to be some integration framework in between to establish the bridge between these two.

Does anyone has already worked on this?Please let us know in details.

Answer (score 0):

See [the Spring Integration reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/). It is quite easy to bridge between the two environments.

```
JMS inbound channel adapter -> AMQP outbound channel adapter

AMQP inbound channel adapter -> JMS outbound channel adapter
```

There are also inbound/outbound gateways for both for request/response messaging.

Comment: is there any specific link for reference. I am quite new for this.